# How can I make my program wait for the user to interact with my JFrame?

Tags: java, actionlistener, wait, notify

I am trying to write a file processing application but the program won't wait for the user to select a file before moving and finishing the function. I've tried to use wait() and notify() to make it stop but the program now freezes and buttons d and e never show up.

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.io.File;

public class pdfEditor {

static JFrame inter = new JFrame("The Point Updater");
static JLabel reminder = new JLabel("Please select a function:");
static boolean i = false;
JButton a, b, c, d, e;
JFileChooser fc;

public static void main(String[] args) {

    //Sets the window
    inter.setSize(750, 250);
    inter.setLocation(100, 150);
    inter.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    inter.setLayout(null);

    //Label for commands for the user
    reminder.setBounds(50, 50, 650, 30);

    //add a button
    JButton b = new JButton("Update Trainings");
    b.setBounds(50, 150, 135, 30);

    JButton c = new JButton("Update Employees");
    c.setBounds(200, 150, 140, 30);

    JButton a = new JButton("Export Points");
    a.setBounds(355, 150, 135, 30);

    //add them to the frame
    inter.add(reminder);
    inter.add(a);
    inter.add(b);
    inter.add(c);

    inter.setVisible(true);

    //Process selection
    //TODO add catches for unformatted spreadsheets
    a.addActionListener(new ActionListener() { //If export Points button is selected

        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
                reminder.setText("Kashikomarimashita!");
                exportPoints();
        }          
    });

    b.addActionListener(new ActionListener() { //If update trainings is selected

        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
                reminder.setText("Make sure the type is Individual Completions and the columns are set to Training, Employee and Date.");
                File file = null;
                try {
                    file = requestInputSpreadsheet();
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                updateTraining(file);
        }          
    });

    c.addActionListener(new ActionListener() { //If update employees is selected

        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
                reminder.setText("Please import a employee list from iScout or Quickbase.");
                File file = null;
                try {
                    file = requestInputSpreadsheet();
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                updateEmployees(file);
        }          
    });
}

//Asks the user for a spreadsheet to be used in processing.
public static File requestInputSpreadsheet() throws InterruptedException{

    //makes file chooser
    JFileChooser fc = new JFileChooser();
    fc.addChoosableFileFilter(new SpreadsheetFilter());
    fc.setAcceptAllFileFilterUsed(false);

    //makes new buttons and label
    JLabel name = new JLabel();
    name.setBounds(180, 100, 270, 30);
    JButton d = new JButton("Choose File...");
    d.setBounds(50, 100, 135, 30);
    JButton e = new JButton("Go!");
    e.setBounds(450, 100, 50, 30);

    inter.add(d);
    SwingUtilities.updateComponentTreeUI(inter);

    //switch for the file chooser if file was chosen successfully
    i = false;
    File file = null;

    d.addActionListener(new ActionListener() { //begins file choosing process

        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {

            int returnVal = fc.showOpenDialog(inter);

            if (returnVal == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION) {

                //processes file and displays name
                File file = fc.getSelectedFile();
                name.setName(file.getName());

                inter.add(name);
                inter.add(e);
                SwingUtilities.updateComponentTreeUI(inter);
            } 

        }          
    });

    e.addActionListener(new ActionListener() { //returns the selected file

        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
            i = true;
            synchronized (e) {
                 e.notify();
            }
        }          
    });

    synchronized(e) {
          e.wait();
    }

    //removes the button!
    inter.remove(d);
    inter.remove(e);
    SwingUtilities.updateComponentTreeUI(inter);

    if (i == true) {
        return file;
    }
    return null;

}




    //Updates completed training list and awards points based on a spreadsheet exported from the database
    public static boolean updateTraining(File file) {

// still working on the processing
        if (file == null) {
        return false;
    } else {
    System.out.println("Updated Training!!");
    return true;
    }
}

//Updates the employee list using an employee list exported from the database
public static boolean updateEmployees(File file) {
    if (file == null) {
        return false;
    } else {
    System.out.println("Updated Employees!!");
    return true;
    }
}

//Creates and exports a spreadsheet with employee names and current points
public static boolean exportPoints() {
    System.out.println("Exported Points!");
    return true;
}
```

}

I included all of the code just in case.

Comment: That's a lot of craziness going on there.  First.  Swing, like most GUI frameworks, is single threaded.  All the "wait" and "notifies" are dangerous and could end up locking up your application (as they wait on and notify one the same thread).  `JFileChooser#showXxx` will create a modal dialog.  This will block the execution flow until the dialog is closed, so you need to work that into your design.  GUIs tend to be event driven (something happens, you respond to it) as apposed to procedural or linear, which you might be use to in a console environment

Comment: In event-driven programs like GUIs, you never *wait* for things to happen. You set up your UI, and you attach event handlers (like `onClick`) to your elements; this code gets run when the user interacts with your UI.

Comment: Thank you for the help!